# Can we fill missing values of different columns in a pandas dataframe in two/three lines of code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I hope you are doing well. I am dealing with a steel dataset having different attributes. I wanted to fill their missing values with their mean. However, rather than doing it separately I want to do it with in two or three lines of codes in a single go. I am trying the following code:

```
empty_list = []
empty_list.append(df.columns[df.isnull().any()])
for names in empty_list:
    df[names].fillna(df[names].mean(),axis=1,inplace=True)
```

First, I append the names of the columns having missing values into a list and try to iterate over that list with filling their missing values in the dataframe with their mean. But it is giving me the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
```

Can someone have any other suggestions of how to do it. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`empty_list` here is not what you intend it to be. You should say

```
empty_list += list(df.columns[df.isnull().any()])
```

or

```
empty_list = df.columns[df.isnull().any()],
```

depending on whether `empty_list` previously had any values in it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . However, I did it like first I specified a list.

Comment: as empty_list = [] and then I appended the names of the columns having null values to that list.

Comment: That isn't what your code does. Try `empty_list += list(df.columns[df.isnull().any()])` instead of `empty_list.append(df.columns[df.isnull().any()])`. You are appending a Series to your list, not a bunch of strings.

Comment: But can you tell me like I am still a newbie in Coding. Like why my code was not able to work. Like what exactly my code was doing rather than what I intend of doing it.

Comment: You wanted `emptylist=[column1, column2, ...]` But what you actually wrote produced `emptylist = [[column1, column2, ...]]` or something similar